# How could I exclude the text from UITextField to be transparent in terms of alpha?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a uitextfield setted the alpha to 0.2, the problem is I can't find how I could set the alpha opacity only to be applied to the background of the UITextField, not also to the text that is inside the UItextField.
Snippet of my code:

```
     self.emailInputField.text = "Enter your Email/Username"
    self.passwordEmailInputField.text = "Enter your Password"
    self.passwordEmailInputField.backgroundColor = .white
    self.emailInputField.backgroundColor = .white
    self.passwordEmailInputField.alpha = 0.1
    self.emailInputField.alpha = 0.1
    self.passwordEmailInputField.textColor = .gray
    self.passwordEmailInputField.textColor = .gray
    self.view.addSubview(self.emailInputField)
    self.view.addSubview(self.passwordEmailInputField)
```

Comment: What about instead `theTextField.backgroundColor = .clear` and no modification of `theTextField.alpha`?

Answer (score 0):

To extend the comment above: you should not set the `alpha` of the field itself to 0.1 if your intent is to only change the background color. Instead, initialize the `backgroundColor` property with alpha:

```
self.passwordEmailInputField.backgroundColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
self.emailInputField.backgroundColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
```